# Should I Store Data Before or After in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This question pertains to good practice rather than a specific use case.
I have the choice to either save information in Mongo documents and then display it to the user or perform mongo queries based on a partial selection of this information to get the rest I need to display.

To clarify, for example, either I could store 10 fields in a document and then display all these fields or perform mongo queries based on 6 of the fields to get the rest.

In one case, the database becomes larger but the loading might be faster and in the other case, the database is smaller but the loading is probably faster

Which one of these options should I choose?

Comment: It ***heavily*** depends on the use case. So there is no general answer for this.

Comment: Would anyone know of any resource to refer to for choosing the right data structures for your web-app?

Comment: There is no ifttt for data models. You have to know the intricacies and choose depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on preference and use case.